# Android: fixed button in each view

Tags: android

Is there a way to make a button fix in the whole application views? I mean instead of adding the button to every xml file and code it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom activity in which you create one time button and every activity you will call, extended to your custom activity will have that button

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your button xml code a different xml file. And to every other activity xml layout you can use the xml tag include like

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or like jack said, create a base activity that creates the buttons and the rest of the activities can extend from it.

Comment: Ok about the include, but still each time i have to code the action of the button in the activity

Comment: You can create a base activity that handles the click and make the activities extend this base activity.